# How to Send Multiple params to JAVA API using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, ajax, http

I have Java API function as bellow :

```
     public Response abc(@FormParam("tenderIdsJsonArray") JSONArray tenderIdsJsonArray, @FormParam("tenderRejectTime") String tenderRejectTime,@FormParam("rejectResonType")  String rejectResonType) {

     }
```

I am sending data from AngularJs

```
     $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: URL,
      data: {bacJsonArray:[1543],RejectTime:"12",rejectResonType:"test"}    
    }).success(function (response) {
      loaderServ.hide();
      resolve(response);
    }).error(function (error) {
      loaderServ.hide();
      reject(error);
    });
```

I am getting all parameters of function as null at API side

where i need to make change

I also tried sending:

```
JSON.stringify({bacJsonArray:[1543],RejectTime:"12",rejectResonType:"test"} 
    })
```

or params:{alldata}

I also tried changing at server side:

```
     public Response abc(JSONArray bacJsonArray,String RejectTime,String rejectResonType) {

     }
```

But in all cases i am recieving Null at server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below way i used and it worked.

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        transformRequest: function(obj) {
            var str = [];
            for(var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
        },
        data: {username: $scope.userName, password: $scope.password}
    }).success(function () {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com',
    data: { test: 'test' }
};

$http(req).then(function(){
    // success
}, function(){
    error
});
```

Comment: can yo give me in above case     $http({
      method: 'POST',

Comment: @pareshm what are you saying ?

Comment: dont want in shorthand form

Comment: @pareshm i don't know about JAVA but passing params to a function is a GET not POST right ? have you tried $http.get instead of $http.post ?

Comment: @pareshm did it help ?

Comment: Nope i want send it to post Request